# Binding static property in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to follow this [article](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/28/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-9-binding-to-static-properties/), the only difference is that I am creating and binding the control in code behind.
Unfortunately it's not working. Here is my sample code :

```
 public partial class ShellWindow
 {
      private static Visibility progressbarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      public static Visibility ProgressbarVisibility
      {
           get { return progressbarVisibility; }
           set
           {
               if (progressbarVisibility == value) return;
               progressbarVisibility = value;
               RaiseStaticPropertyChanged("ProgressbarVisibility");
           }
      }
      public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
      public static void RaiseStaticPropertyChanged(string propName)
      {
           EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> handler = StaticPropertyChanged;
           if (handler != null)
               handler(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
     }
}
```

And I am binding like this

```
var binding = new Binding("ShellWindow.ProgressbarVisibility") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
       progressbar = new CircularProgressBar ();
  progressbar.SetBinding(VisibilityProperty,
                             binding);
```

I think I am missing something, but I am not sure where I am wrong.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article says to use:

```
{Binding (local:Repository.Color)}
```

Since `local:` has no meaning outside a XAML file, I don't think it's possible to construct a binding with a string.

You can also assign a [PropertyPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.PropertyPath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the `Binding.Path` property, and [this PropertyPath constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587924%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts `PropertyInfo`. To use this constructor, the path string needs to be specified in tokenized format (described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Thus:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(ShellWindow).GetProperty("ProgressbarVisibility");
var propertyPath = new PropertyPath("(0)", propertyInfo);
var binding = new Binding() { Path = propertyPath, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
```